# Ruby - how to pass uploaded file to method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, methods, upload

I have a form for file uploaded. In the controller method, I want to pass this file to a method that will work with this file, something like this:

in controller:

```
  def uploaded_file
    file_handler= ::FilesOper.analizeFile(params[:upl_file])
  end
```

If I do this, I'll get this error message:

```
can't convert ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile into String
```

I thought that I am passing everything what is related to the uploaded file, so what's wrong?

Comment: Try `pramas[:upl_file].read`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def uploaded_file
   file_handler= ::FilesOper.analizeFile(params[:upl_file]).to_s
end
```